# broadcast a message in omnet++ with timestamp

Tags: c++, signals, omnet++, broadcast

I m trying to broadcast a message to multiple nodes from one node then the receiving nodes will broadcast the message between each other , this message will include a timestamp to be more precise IM trying to implement totally order broadcast ABCAST  , this is my cc file together with my NED file code , can anyone help me to know what to fix or to add, thank you

`

```
void Res::initialize()
{
// TODO - Generated method body
seq=0;
signalID = registerSignal("arrival");
timestamp = 1;
if (getIndex() == 0) {
       //Boot the process scheduling the initial message as a self-message.
       char msgname[20];
       sprintf(msgname, "node-%d", getIndex());
       cMessage *msg = new cMessage(msgname);
       scheduleAt(0.0, msg);
   }

}
void Res::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{

if (getIndex() == 3) {
// Message arrived.
EV << "Message " << msg << " arrived.\n";
delete msg;
 } else {
forwardMessage(msg);
 }

 }
void Res::forwardMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
int n = gateSize("out");
int k = intuniform(0, n-1);
EV << "Forwarding message " << msg << " on port out [" << k << "]\n";

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cTimestampedValue tmp(timestamp, msg);
    emit(signalID, &tmp);
    cMessage *copy = msg->dup();
    send(copy, "out", i);
}
}
   simple Broadcast
   {



    parameters:
    @display("i=block/routing");

gates:
    //inout gate[];
    input in[];  // declare in[] and out[] to be vector gates
    output out[]; 

}
network networ
{
types:
submodules:
    node[4]: Broadcast ;
connections:

    
    
    
          node[0].out++ --> Channel --> node[1].in++;
          //node[1].out++ --> Channel --> node[0].in++;
          node[3].out++ --> Channel --> node[2].in++;
          node[2].out++ --> Channel --> node[3].in++;
          node[0].out++ --> Channel --> node[2].in++;
          node[0].out++ --> Channel --> node[3].in++;
        


}
channel Channel extends ned.DelayChannel
{
delay = 100ms;
}
```

`

Comment: Welcome at SO! First of all, you should define own message - take a look at [tictoc tutorial](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part4/#44-defining-our-message-class). Moreover, could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75501039/edit) your question and add the NED file of your network?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you don't use inet packets which all have `CreationTimeTag`, you need to define a variable in your message that will hold the timestamp from the sender side by assigning `simTime()` to the appropriate field and reading that field at the receiver side

Comment: IM new  to omnet so can you please give me an code example ,  I would be grateful .

Comment: inet/applications/udpapp/UdpBasicBurst.cc, L.: 315 `payload->setTimestamp()` here the timestamp is set by a sender and L: 261 `pk->getTimestamp()` is processed by a receiver